# Error in a recursive template function using STXXL templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, stxxl

I need to optimize the block size `BlkSize_` parameter of the stxxl vector for partial sums finding using a simple grid search. As the only way to specify it for a stxxl vector seems to use it as a template parameter in vector generator, I understand that I want to use some recursive template function that would output time used by partial_sum function given a block size template parameter. I also need to carry a vector size as a parameter.

Here is my code:

```
template<unsigned int size>
void TestPartialSum(int N) {
  typedef stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<
          int,
          1,
          1, 
          size,
          stxxl::RC,
          stxxl::lru>::result xxlvector;

  xxlvector v(N);
  xxlvector res(N);
  iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 5, 2);
  std::cerr << "N = " << N <<  std::endl;
  Profiler profiler;
  std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), res.begin());
  TestPartialSum<size / 2>(N);
  return;
}
```

But though `struct stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR` takes exactly 6 parameters (`class Tp_, unsigned int PgSz_, unsigned int Pages_, unsigned int BlkSize_, class AllocStr_, stxxl::pager_type Pager_`), I receive this:

```
error: too few template-parameter-lists
```

for a `typedef` line.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: @doctorlove, on a `typedef...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a `typename` to tell that `result` is a type:

```
  typedef typename stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<
          int,
          1,
          1, 
          size,
          stxxl::RC,
          stxxl::lru>::result xxlvector;
```

The interpretation of `result` depends on the template argument `size` in your code, and there is a special rule in C++ to interpret it as a non-type **unless** the `typename` keyword is used.
See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more info.